# how to make blog list view of protostar template joomla

Tags: protostar

I am using protostar template for creating blog but on home page it show whole content of blog but we want short description of blog. we want to display blog as list view.

I have check on home page setting but i did not found anything for list view. also we need to display one image and title of blog.
like following image

[image]

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  While you wait for support, please take the [tour].

Comment: Have you inserted a Read More link below the text that you want to appear in the Blog layout? https://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_an_Article_into_an_introduction_with_a_link_to_read_more

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this simple steps:

- In your articles, you can see a tab called **"Images and Links"**

[image: Images & Links Tab]

Here you can add an **Intro Image**, for example a 200px * 200px jpg. These will be the images like in your screenshot. The **Full Article image** is the image you see when you open the article.

- In the Content Tab, you only need to select the text you want to show in the blog view and add a **"Read More"** to hide the rest of the content from this view.